# What is wrong with the if/else syntax in this code?

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.7

Why will this code not work?  Are the indentations wrong or is the code wrong?

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input('Enter a word.')
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else print "empty":
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I am trying to learn Python through Codecademy.

Comment: The error message you got did provide a valuable hint:  A `SyntaxError` with a `^` pointing at the `print` token.  This means the parser actually expected a different token here – namely the colon.

Comment: Also note that the idiomatic way to test for a non-empty string in Python is `if original`, not `if len(original) > 0`.

Answer (score 8):

```
else print "empty":
    ^             ^
```

needs to have `:` after the `else` and *not* after the string you are printing, ie

```
else: print "empty"
    ^              ^
```

so, you had `:`, but in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 4):

You either need to move the colon to just after the `else`:

```
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else: print "empty"
```

Or if you prefer, you can use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
print original if len(original) > 0 else "empty"
```

Comment: If you really want to use some form of conditional expression, I'd strongly prefer `print original or "empty"` in this particular case.  (I'd actually prefer the explicit `if` statement.)

Answer (score 2):

What you did:

```
    print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
    original = raw_input('Enter a word.')
    if len(original) > 0:
        print original
    else print "empty":
```

What you need to do:

```
    print("Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!")
    original = raw_input('Enter a word.')
    if len(original) > 0:
        print("original")
    else:
        print("empty")
```

you missed out brackets, put a colon in the wrong place and didn't go onto another line on the last bit. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial has excellent example of all types of statements you'll need:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

```
if condition_1:
    (execute)
elif condition_2:
    (execute)
else:
    (execute)
```